# condition Gumbel distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let X be the Gumbel distribution:
$$ F(x)\equiv P(X<x)= exp(-exp(-x))\,. $$

Given $X>c$, then the cumulative distribution function can be written as:
$$ P(X> c + t \mid X > c) = \frac{1-F(c+t)}{1- F(c)}$$

Are there closed forms for the expectation or variance of this condition Gumbel distribution? i.e. closed forms for:

$$ E(X \mid X>c) ,\, Var(X \mid X>c)$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "[Gumbel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution)," nor Grumbel.

Comment: @ClementC. corrected. Thanks!

Comment: You can express $E(X|X>c)=c+\frac {\int_c^\infty P(X>t)}{P(X>c)}$ and compute the integral in terms of exponential integral after substitution $u=e^{-x}$ to get $E(X|X>c)=c-\frac {Ei(-e^c)}{1-e^{-e^{-x}}}$.

Comment: @A.S. correct me if I get wrong: $\int_c^\infty P(X>t)dt =  \int_c^\infty 1-e^{-e^{-t}}dt =\int_{e^{-c}}^0 \frac{1-e^{-u}}{u}du$, how to connect this with the exponential integral?

Comment: I messed up a bit: Take an integral starting at $x\to 0$ instead and break up the integrand: $\int_0^{e^{-c}} \frac{1-e^{-u}}{u}du=\lim_{x\to 0}(\ln(e^{-c})-\ln(x)-E_1(x)+E_1(e^{-c}))=-c+\gamma+E_1(e^{-c})$ and that gives you a faster convergent series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Convergent_series

Comment: Looks right! Thank you so much!